# Download Excel file in browser using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, oracle-adf

I have seen this question so many places, But still not able to solve my requirement.

I have written code to generate excelsheet in Apache POI in ADF using Java and need to download it in browser as application will be in server side not always in my local machine.

Initially I tried code:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(home + "/Downloads/" + "excel1" + filename + ".xls"));
```

It was downloading. But it is downloading only on my machine. It's not downloading on other machine.

Another solution:

```
file = new File(home + "/Downloads/" + "excel" + filename + ".xls");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start " + file);
```

But it is not working..

Another solution:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.reset();
response.setContentType(“application/vnd.ms-excel”);
response.setHeader(“Content-Disposition”, “attachment; filename=\"excel.xlsx");
workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
fc.responseComplete();
```

But this solution also does not work.

Comment: The last solution with `response.getOutputStream()` should work; just that `workbook.flush()` or something like that seems to be needed before you assert with `fc.responseComplete();` that all is written.

Comment: Actually I tried workbook.flush(). but it was not downloading.

Comment: I removed fc.responseComplete(); from the code.. but then even it's not downloading @JoopEggen

Comment: Last solution looks almost ok to me too ... have you tried to close() the workbook and flush() the outputstream?

Comment: **Split the problem to find the cause (temporarily).** Store the workbook as server file and check that. Deliver a static Excel file. A pain, but even tom seems confident that your last solution looks correct.

Comment: Yes I tried both the options but it's not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a suggestion to try to solve your problem.

I usually create a servlet that has the responsibility of downloading files in various formats: xls, pdf...

Here is an example of how this can be done:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        String contentType = null;

        if (fileName.endsWith("xls")) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        } else if (fileName.endsWith("pdf")) {
            contentType = "application/pdf";
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("File type not found");
        }

        byte[] file = getFileOnServer(fileName);

        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        response.setHeader("charset", "iso-8859-1");
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        response.setContentLength(file.length);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(file, 0, file.length);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    private byte[] getFileOnServer(String fileName) {
        //implement your method to get the file in byte[]
        return null;
    }

}
```

So, you can call your servlet by URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/downloadServlet?fileName=myExcel.xls
```

or Form:

```xml
<form id="myDownloadServlet" action="downloadServlet" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="fileName" name="fileName" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnDownload" name="btnDownload" value="Download File" />
</form>
```

Don't forget to configure your web.xml or use the annotation @WebServlet.

I hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

A more "professional" solution is to use Excel Api's for java, as Apache POI or JXL.

Here an example using JXL:

https://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips-100035/93-jexcel/418-how-do-i-output-an-excel-file-from-a-servlet.html

And here one more using Apache POI:

https://programtalk.com/java/download-excel-using-servlet/

I hope this can helps you. 
Best wishes!